# How does google protect its javascripts against being executed by bots?

Tags: javascript, bots

I want to make certain areas of my website accessible to browser users only, and not accessible to automated multithread bots. I am doing this to protect my data, and this is one of the measures I plan to use.

I thought of requiring all the requests to contain a pair of numbers, which must be computed with javascript, which is going to be obfuscated and obscured. But, after that, there's nothing that should stop a bot writer from grabbing a javascrpt bot engine like htmlunit and just executing the javascripts.

Google seems to had solved this problem somehow. I remember that most times I run HtmlUnit on a page with adwords enabled, the script engine crashed. Yet, in real browsers, the pages work just fine.

There must be a trick to it. Can anyone point me to a good info on how I could do this on my page?

Comment: Could you provide more background on why you're looking to implement this?  Is a robots.txt file not stringent enough for what you want?

Comment: I'm creating a website, which is going to have proprietary data on it. and I want it to be accessible to legit users, and I want to make the mass extraction of that data as difficult as possible. robots.txt will be honored by legit bots and not honored by extractor bots

Comment: Seems like you either need proper authorization/authentication or at least (sadly) CAPTCHA. Bots are smarter than you might think

Comment: Bots usually can solve the captcha pretty easily, and the captchas annoy the real users. I'd rather try and do this with the javascript, if I can figure out how this is done

Comment: Just setup a login system. That's the only way to do it. Bots can run headless WebKit renderers that execute JavaScript in order to scrape data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I'd implement some type of authentication.  Of course, with respect to how big and known your user base is.  Some options are:

1. **Have data included from javascript file or ajax call.**  Most bots won't scrape javascript-included text off of a webpage.  Maybe load a blank page, give a short delay (2-3 seconds), and then load the content.  That way, most (?) bots will simply detect a blank page.
2. **HTTP Authentication** would require that users enter a username and password, but it's very simple to manage.
3. **Captcha**
4. **User accounts** using maybe php.  This may be more overhead than you want though.

Answer (score -1):

It's always hard to find a balance between usability and security. Most (advanced)  bots can parse javascript and even big companies like Facebook or Google are having trouble with fighting spam and other harmfull bots.

Most answers here above can help you make it harder for bots. Some possible solutions with a minimal impact on usability are:

**facebook login**
The user doesn't need to reregister and can use his facebook account to login.

Url: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.0

**Google captcha**
The capcha engine from google is quite good and easy to implement.
The engine has also not been broken yet by a bot.

Url: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html